# God rays shader - Trouble with sun position

Tags: opengl, c++, directx11

I have found a shader that I like here: https://www.shadertoy.com/view/4dyXWy

The code for the fragment shader from the link above is:

```
#define DITHER          //Dithering toggle
#define QUALITY     0   //0- low, 1- medium, 2- high

#define DECAY       .974
#define EXPOSURE    .24
#if (QUALITY==2)
 #define SAMPLES    64
 #define DENSITY    .97
 #define WEIGHT     .25
#else
#if (QUALITY==1)
 #define SAMPLES    32
 #define DENSITY    .95
 #define WEIGHT     .25
#else
 #define SAMPLES    16
 #define DENSITY    .93
 #define WEIGHT     .36
#endif
#endif

void mainImage( out vec4 fragColor, in vec2 fragCoord )
{
    vec2 uv = fragCoord.xy / iResolution.xy;

    vec2 coord = uv;
    vec2 lightpos = texture(iChannel0, uv).zw;

    float occ = texture(iChannel0, uv).x; //light
    float obj = texture(iChannel0, uv).y; //objects
    float dither = texture(iChannel1, fragCoord/iChannelResolution[1].xy).r;    

    vec2 dtc = (coord - lightpos) * (1. / float(SAMPLES) * DENSITY);
    float illumdecay = 1.;

    for(int i=0; i<SAMPLES; i++)
    {
        coord -= dtc;
        #ifdef DITHER
            float s = texture(iChannel0, coord+(dtc*dither)).x;
        #else
            float s = texture(iChannel0, coord).x;
        #endif
        s *= illumdecay * WEIGHT;
        occ += s;
        illumdecay *= DECAY;
    }

    fragColor = vec4(vec3(0., 0., obj*.333)+occ*EXPOSURE,1.0);
}
```

That is in GLSL, but I am using DirectX 11. I've been able to port it across quite easily, but I feel like I have some knowledge gaps that are making it hard for me to get correct. For example, I don't understand the difference between `texture(iChannel0, uv).x` and `texture(iChannel0, uv).r` if someone wouldn't mind explaining ( I understand sampling the colour channels but xyz while sampling?).
I also do not understand the channel resolution. Is it the dimensions of the 2D texture that I'm rendering to? Or perhaps the ratio of the texture?

Here is what I have come up with so far, just the bare minimum of changes to get it working:

```
SamplerState g_samSampler   : register( s0 );
Texture2D g_texInfo         : register( t0 );

#define DITHER
#define DECAY       0.974f
#define EXPOSURE    0.24f
#define SAMPLES     64
#define DENSITY     0.97f
#define WEIGHT      0.25f

struct PixelInput
{
    float4 vPosition : SV_POSITION;
    float2 vTexCoord : TEXCOORD0;
};

float4 PS( PixelInput input ) : SV_TARGET
{
    float2 uv = input.vTexCoord;

    float2 coord = uv;
    float2 lightpos = g_texInfo.Sample( g_samSampler, uv ).zw; //TAKE NOTE OF THIS LINE

    float occ = g_texInfo.Sample( g_samSampler, input.vTexCoord ).g; //light
    float obj = g_texInfo.Sample( g_samSampler, input.vTexCoord ).b; //objects
    float dither = g_texInfo.Sample( g_samSampler, uv/float2( 4.f, 3.f ) ).x;  

    float2 dtc = (coord - lightpos) * (1.f / float(SAMPLES) * DENSITY);
    float illumdecay = 1.;

    for(int i=0; i<SAMPLES; i++)
    {
        coord -= dtc;

        #ifdef DITHER
            float s = g_texInfo.Sample( g_samSampler, coord+(dtc*dither) ).g;
        #else
            float s = g_texInfo.Sample( g_samSampler, input.vTexCoord ).g;
        #endif

        s *= illumdecay * WEIGHT;
        occ += s;
        illumdecay *= DECAY;
    }

    return float4(float3(0.f, 0.f, obj*.333f)+occ*EXPOSURE,1.f);
}
```

Please note that my green channel of the passed in texture `g_texInfo` stores the light texture (the white circle for the sun) and the blue channel stores the light occluders.
I am doing this as a post processing effect on a screen quad. (Is this correct?)
My suspicion is the line `float2 lightpos = g_texInfo.Sample( g_samSampler, uv ).zw;` is causing the trouble - I don't really understand this part - how can I find the position of the sun?

Here's what I'm receiving from my current shader, it appears that the light rays are being emitted in the wrong direction.

[image]
When I shift the camera so that the sun is in the top left, it gives the correct effect, it is also occluded properly when putting an object in the way.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In GLSL (like HLSL), a vec4 (float4 in HLSL) has three different ways to access its four values.  You can use (rgba), or (xyzw), or (stpq).  They're all identical to each other;  Asking for `vector.r` gets you the same value as `vector.x` or `vector.s`, so use whichever you prefer.  (General best practices suggest using 'rgba' if it's a color, or 'xyzw' if it's a position in 3D/4D space, or 'stpq' if it's texture coordinates.. which amusingly we refer to as 'uv' coordinates even though you can't use either `u` or `v` to get the individual components from it.  But do what makes you happy;  they're all interchangeable!)

In the original code, you had this:

```cpp
    vec2 lightpos = texture(iChannel0, uv).zw;

    float occ = texture(iChannel0, uv).x; //light
    float obj = texture(iChannel0, uv).y; //objects
```

The obvious issue I see with your port is that you have converted the above to:

```cpp
    float2 lightpos = g_texInfo.Sample( g_samSampler, uv ).zw; //TAKE NOTE OF THIS LINE

    float occ = g_texInfo.Sample( g_samSampler, input.vTexCoord ).g; //light
    float obj = g_texInfo.Sample( g_samSampler, input.vTexCoord ).b; //objects
```

You've moved the channels around!  'zw' (which is equivalent to 'ba') is the same, but you've moved the 'x' ('r') channel to 'g', and the 'y' channel to 'b', re-using the channel you're otherwise using for the lightpos.

That's probably the source of your troubles.  (along with the identical issue a few lines further down, when sampling light values inside the loop)

Regarding your other question, about `iChannelResolution`, that's a custom ShaderToy thing.  It's a uniform variable which holds the width and height of a texture, in pixels.  Here, it appears to be being used to grab the individual pixels of a texture that holds a dithering pattern.  You can easily create your own version of that, but it isn't there for you by default in either GLSL or HLSL.

By contrast, `iResolution` (another custom ShaderToy thing) is the resolution of the destination image.  By default, ShaderToy shaders receive a `fragCoord` input which tells them the coordinates of the pixel being rendered (measured in pixels).  Dividing the fragCoord by iResolution gives you a [0,0]->[1,1] value which is useful for sampling from textures.  Most ShaderToy shaders do that near the start of their code, and this one is no exception.